# Finding linear mappings $f, g$ with given properties.

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm having trouble finding two linear maps $f : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $g : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that the image of $f$ is equal to the kernel which equals $g$ is equal an axis.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about projections?

Comment: What about projections then? Seems pretty easy to meet your requirements

Comment: Hey, I went about your idea. To map to the $x$ axis, we need to map to $y = 0$. So I think I would need to project $(x, y)^{T}$ to $(a, 0)$ for some $a$? The only thing I can come up with is the zero matrix?

Comment: I believe that the matrix will should have trignometric functions in it. I'm having difficulty now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the $x$ axis forms a subspace of the real plane (whose equation is $y = 0$ as a line), and along with the $y$ axis provides a coordinate system for $\mathbb R^2$, in that every point can be represented uniquely as a linear combination of the unit vector pointing in the $x$ and the $y$ axis directions.

The idea, therefore, is to take a point in $\mathbb R^2$ and consider only its $x$ value, setting the $y$ value to zero : this automatically ensures the image to be a subset of the $x$ axis. More rigorously, define $F(x,y) = (x,0)$. This is a linear transformation(check this) whose image is the $x$ axis, as I explained earlier. You may try to write the matrix(in standard basis) for this if you like.

---

Now, what about $g$? The point is again, that if the kernel is to be *exactly* the $x$ axis, then every point of non-zero $y$ coordinate goes to some non-zero number pair.

The answer should now be in front of you : $g(x,y) = (0,y)$. Now, $g$ will send a point to zero only if the $y$ coordinate is zero i.e. the point is on the $x$ axis. You may again see the matrix of $g$ in standard basis if you like.

---

Attempting to find matrices satisfying constraints before working out the geometric aspects can sometimes become a blind search for many variables satisfying some constraints, so sometimes it is better to see if you can get a good picture of a desirable linear transformation by seeing what it does to a point $(x_1,...,x_n)$, rather than as a matrix.

---

The usual "computation of matrices given linear transformation" with standard basis works as follows :order the basis : in our case, it is $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$. Now, $F(1,0) = (1,0)$ and $F(0,1) = (0,0)$. Therefore, writing these image vectors as columns, $F = \begin{bmatrix}1 \quad 0 \\ 0 \quad 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Similarly, $G(1,0) = (0,0)$ and $G(0,1) = (0,1)$, so this matrix $G = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \quad 0 \\ 0 \quad 1\end{bmatrix}$. Check that $FG = 0$ (Since $\mbox{im} F = \ker G$, obviously $GF = 0$). However, below I give an example where $FG \neq 0$.

Comment: How can I compute the matrices for $f$ and $g$?? I've been trying to do so. It should have trig in it, right?

Comment: There is no trigonometry involved. If you like I will compute the matrices also.

Comment: Yes, that would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Edited. Please check.

Comment: thanks so much, but is there a way to get $FG \neq 0$ ?

Comment: Yes. Try $F(x,y) = (y,0)$. The matrix of this will be $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \quad 1 \\ 0 \quad 0\end{bmatrix}$. The same $G$ is fine.